# oracle installer disappear before completing installation

Tags: oracle

I have downloaded oracle 19c 64 bit for my 64 bit OS from official site and extract it.when i run setup then it disappear before the completion of installation. similar this happened with 18c and also 11g. it did not return me even single error. It just simply disappeared.
Is there any help? How can oracle 19c be install.

Comment: Which "64 bit OS" is it? Its full name, please.

Comment: windows 10 pro education   64-bit operating system, x64-based processor .  Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5300U CPU @ 2.30GHz   2.29 GHz .  with 8gb ram

Comment: How did you invoke the setup installer?  Exactly what command?  Please [edit] your question to add this information.  Have you tried invoking the setup command from a "Command Prompt" window?

Comment: I have downloaded simply in zip file on my windows system. And then i unzip it. Then i click the setup.exe file and run it but it open for a while just for 2 to 3 second and then disappear. Like cmd is not able to run this setup. Actually it should simply run and then after it should appear next process like user account creating settings etc path settings etc I mean the process after installation but it didn't

Comment: In this week i have  exam on Oracle database administration but my windows system is not installing oracle even i have tried 11g 18c also . Just 18c give me notification that installation is cancel with this error "system is not modified".. how can i modify system?